# Computing Percentage c#

Tags: c#

Hello guys/gals I need some help in my program that calculate the total numbers by dividing into three, first is 80% of total 2nd is 10% of total and thr last is 10% of total. I have tried it to convert to double but if the total is 5 the first one will output 4 and the 2nd is 0 and 3rd is 0 which is wrong because I am expecting the total of output as it is.
Here is my code

```
    Double total = 5;
    Double a,b,c,tot;
    a = total*0.80;
    b = total*0.10;
    c = total*0.10;
   tot = a+b+c;
   Int convert = Convert.ToInt32(tot)
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: You should show what you have tried, it sounds like your dividing an integer by an integer

Comment: First see [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question

Comment: I do convert it to Double first to calculate total*0.80 for first and to output this on label i converted it to Int then to string. Which is good if the percentage is 60 40 20, which is when I convert double into int it automatically round it off. But not in 80 10 10.

Comment: Please post your code. Your explanation makes things inexplicable.

Comment: I have already update my post

Comment: ... Why do you convert it to an integer at the end?..

Comment: To round it off. Because it works when the percentage is 50% 30% and 20%. 5 gets 3,1,1. Which is basically 2.5 1.5 0.5. Btw i need it by whole number

Comment: Int convert = tot gets error cannot explicit Int to doublr

Comment: So if total is 5, a = 4, b = 0.5 and c=0.5 what do you expect b and c to be if you convert them to an int?

Comment: The one is will get 1 and another is 0. I need to produce it whole numbers in any of a,b,c

Comment: Depending upon situation the sum of 4,0,0 is not the equal of total and if the total is 7 it provides 6,1,1 which is not the total of sum. The only correct on my situation is if the total is 10 which is 8,1,1

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

`Int convert = Convert.ToInt32(tot + 0.5)`

This way, `tot` will take the nearest integer. Knowing that 2.5 for example will be 3 and so on.

But you might need it to `a`, `b` and `c` like this:

`tot = Convert.ToInt32(a + 0.5) + Convert.ToInt32(b + 0.5) + Convert.ToInt32(c + 0.5);`

Comment: Cannot implicity convert type double to int

Comment: Do the conversion. Try now @shampoo

Comment: I mean the total itself is not the problem. It produces a =4 which is 80% b = 0 and a = 0. That is the case how can I divide it to percentage above

Comment: See new edit and `tot` will be the `convert` value and as an int @shampo